# Creating a Calender View Summary Report

Tags: asp.net, calendar, fullcalendar, report, summary

I want to display a calender view summary report, where on page load I can display all the dates in the current month and a particular count for date.  On mouse hover over the date another grid summary should pop up showing more details in breakage. (Look for the attached image for more details.)

Is there any asp control to do the same? I Looked at some Calendar controls from asp, but they don't tend to meet my need.

(Or else I am planning to do a customized grid view of rows and columns and link them to dates of the month and display other details.)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DayPilot lite is an excellent free calendar component that may do what you need and there is also a full version to buy with added features.

[DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/)